# Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi Driver for Dell Inspiron 3520

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Inspiron 3520. Everything works properly, but my wireless driver is not working. I used many commands but failed to install.

The link which I used is here: [Dell Inspiron 3520 installed - can't get wifi to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268233/dell-inspiron-3520-installed-12-10-cant-get-wifi-to-work)

Comment: What is your wireless card and which driver are you trying to use for it?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `uname -a`?

Comment: sir i install this driver wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Run : `sudo rmmod wl` then `sudo modprobe wl`

Answer (score 2):

**Disable the secure boot from your BIOS settings.**

Install the `linux-headers` package then install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Unload conflicting driver:

```
sudo rmmod b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: bundle of thanks its working after disable the secure boot

Answer (score 0):

If random googling for your model's wireless chipset is accurate, you have a BCM43142-based card. This is only supported by Broadcom's proprietary driver as far as I can tell.
Historically I have had a LOT of trouble getting the proprietary driver to work, but it has been several years since I used a broadcom card and the situation may have changed. Here are some suggestions to help:

First, blacklist the b43, b43legacy, ssb, b44, and bcma drivers. They can interfere with the proprietary broadcom one.

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root, and add the following:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist ssb
blacklist b44
blacklist b43legacy
```

Then, using an ethernet connection, install the `wl` driver:

```
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Then reboot. It may be possible to use `rmmod` to unload the blacklisted modules, but I've had more luck rebooting.

[The Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) may be relevant here. Ubuntu is based on Debian, and back when I used Ubuntu I think it was this page that finally got my card working. Check the "known issues" section if it isn't working very well after a reboot.

Comment: Sir also do this but for ur first solution  blacklist.conf ....There is an error you have no permission to save the file

Comment: i also use this link:     https://askubuntu.com/questions/822771/wifi-disconection-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-a-dell-inspiron-15-laptop       
but when i load this command   (sudo modprobe wl) i get error sudo wl not found